# My hashing algorithm is being given the same data yet producing a different answer

Tags: python, database, sqlite, hash

I have created a hashing algorithm used to hash a users password.

```
def randomsalt():
    salt = 256*3//4
    return secrets.token_urlsafe(salt)

def hash_algo(salt, password):
    salt = bytes(salt, 'utf-8')
    password = bytes(password, 'utf-8')
    digest = hmac.new(salt, password, hashlib.sha256)
    return digest.hexdigest()
```

I then use these two functions to hash the password here

```
password = hash_algo(salt, password)
cursor.execute("""INSERT INTO users (username, password, credits, salt) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)""",
        (username, password, credits, salt))                
connect.commit()
cursor.close()
connect.close()
```

1. The issue arises when a user attempts to log in and provides a valid password.
   I hash the users entered password with the same function using all the same data and then compare it to the hashed password stored in the database. Shown below

```
username = input("enter username:")
password = input("enter password:")
cursor.execute(f"""SELECT salt FROM users WHERE username = '{username}';""")
hashkey = cursor.fetchone()
connect.commit()
cursor.execute(f"""SELECT password FROM users WHERE username = '{username}';""")
hashedpass = cursor.fetchone()
connect.commit()
hashkey = convertselect(hashkey, "non")
hashedpass = convertselect(hashedpass, "non")
if hash_algo(hashkey, password) == hashedpass:
    cursor.execute(f"""SELECT username FROM users WHERE username = '{username}' AND password = '{password}';""")
    print("working")
else:
    print("not working")
```

however they do not match as the algorithm has produced a completely different password and my code outputs "not working"

I checked if my algorithm was wrong by providing the same information to it twice however it provided the same hashed password as it should

Therefore my conclusion is  that I cannot be providing the same information but I don't see how.

Comment: The salt is different each time. You need to save the salt in the table, then use the saved salt when validating.

Comment: Please don't follow this high-level approach. Prefer [argon2id](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argon2) instead. Among other desirable properties, it will keep salt+hash together for you. https://pypi.org/project/argon2

Comment: turns out it was because when a variable is assigned a select statement it comes with brackets quotation marks and a comma which messed it up, getting rid of them it works perfectly now. Thanks for the advice tho :)

Comment: Also, SQL quoting shouldn't ever be an issue. Please use `?` bind variables. https://xkcd.com/327

Comment: HMAC is not designed for password storage in a database so why are you using it? This problem is your own making and is also _not_ industry standard

Comment: this is a school project i'm doing so i'm very novice to this, what should I be using for password storage in databses if not HMAC